# Best practices for handling platform exclusive features in KMM

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I have an existing iOS app and I'm trying out KMM. Ideally, when launched, the app would be available both for Android and iOS, but I'd like for existing iOS users not to lose their current content.

I started building a `MigratorService` in `iosMain`, as all it's going to be doing is dealing with platform-specific models, but then I didn't have a way to call it from `commonMain`. So I either:

- Move all the code I've done in `iosMain` to `commonMain`. Although there is the potential risk of exposing old iOS related code to Android, in reality this would never happen since the migration only happens for iOS.
- Create an expect `MigratorService` in commonMain, with the actual implementation being on `iosMain`. But this approach implies also adding a complete `no-op` version of `MigratorService` in `androidMain`. Which is exposing an API that doesn't really do what is expected.

Which one would be considered the best practice in KMM and why? Or is there another alternative to tackle these situations?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by platform specific models? Ideally, you should have common models for API responses or data etc. that would reside in `commonMain` for both platforms.

Comment: Yes, I'll be redoing the models in `commonMain`, but users coming from the previous versions of the app will have persisted data from the native models. When they update the app I want to migrate their persisted data from the native models to the new models I'll be implementing in `commonMain`

Comment: "persisted data from the native models" that sounds like something very specific. I think your question would need more code with one sample of what you're trying to achieve. That way, I can try to imitate your problem locally and see how to solve it efficiently.

Comment: as an example, let's look at enums. Even by naming convention, Swift enums are very different from Kotlin ones. You won't be able to simply import a JSON object that was persisted through Swift and expect it to decode 100% into a Kotlin object. That is why I wanted to introduce a service that would read these JSON legacy objects and massage the contents to correctly create a Kotlin object. This service only makes sense to exist in iOS.

Comment: Sounds like you're already solving that problem using `MigrationService` that behaves like a wrapper between new and existing models. Not sure what the issue is at this point. Again, I think it would be easier to discuss further if you've two set of code examples to discuss pros and cons rather than just text.